# Module and Class with the same name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-3, module, namespaces

Say, for example I have **module 'A'** and **module 'B'**. In **module B**, there is a class called **'A'**, just like **module 'A'**. Inside this class, I want to reference **A**::ClassC, where '**A**' is the module, but I am getting errors because it thinks I am referencing the class **A**, which does not have ClassC. Can I get around this? Or do I need to rename one? (I would like to avoid that as much as possible)

edit:

Here is an example of my current implementation that isn't working for reference.

```
    >moduleA
        >classC.rb
    >moduleB
        >classA.rb
        >classB.rb
```

classA.rb:

```
module B
    class A < classB

    do something with A::ClassC

    end
end
```

The error is `uninitialized constant ModuleB::ClassA::ClassC`

Comment: "I am getting errors" – Those errors will tell you what is wrong, where the error is occurring, and how you got there. Without those errors, it is impossible to tell what is going on. Please construct a [mre]. Note that all three words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your actual code, rather you should create a simplified example demonstrating the problem. It should be *minimal*, i.e. not contain anything that is not required to demonstrate the problem. It should be *reproducible*, so that if I copy&paste and run the code, I see the same problem you see.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the two constants are in different namespaces, so there should be no problem and no error, but without the error and the code, it is impossible to tell what might be going on.

Comment: _"I have module A and module B ..."_ – just show your code Instead of describing it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, sorry. The error is `uninitialized constant ModuleB::ClassA::ClassC`. Thanks.

Comment: That error cannot possibly come from the code you posted. There is no `ModuleB` in your code, there is no `ClassA` in your code. There must be something else going on that you are not showing us. Without that, it is impossible to figure out what might be going wrong. As I said in my earlier comment, from your description it sounds like those two constants are in different namespaces, so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  the scope resolution operator `::` to decide from which scope class `C` can be found.
In your case you want a "main" scope, so use `::` operator as a prefix - `::A::C`

```
module A
  class C
    def name
      "I am class C from module A"
    end
  end
end

module B
  class A
    def test
      ::A::C.new.name
    end
  end
end

name = B::A.new.test
# => "I am class C from module A"
```